# Filter List to render or conditionally render list's elements

Tags: reactjs, typescript, front-end-optimization

I want to render a list (or array) of objects but that rendering would be based on some boolean condition. What is the most optimized way to approach this:

```
const list: object[] = [....]  // Coming from somewhere else

const (renderList, setRenderList): object[] = []  // List that will be rendered

// option1
useEffect(() => {
    setRenderList(list.filter(...));  // On every change in list, filter the rendered list based on the condition
},[list])

renderList.map((el) =><RenderThis />);

// option2 
// no use of renderList
// filter each element of renderList and conditionally render it

list.map((el) => {
    if(el.something === condition) && <Render />
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely don't need `useEffect` here.

If the boolean condition is cheap then go with option 2:

```
list.map((item) => checkCondition(item) && <Item ... />)
```

Otherwise use `useMemo`:

```
const filteredList = useMemo(() => list.filter(checkCondition), [list]));
```

If `list` hasn't changed react will use the previous value.